# Building a dev environment in Heroku for Phoenix

Tags: heroku, deployment, elixir, phoenix-framework, development-environment

I'm trying to set up Phoenix 1.2 so that I have two Heroku environments: one for dev/testing (which will keep the this-app-12345.herokuapp.com url), and a standard production environment.

Currently, I set up my app the usual way:

```
mix phoenix.new my_app
cd my_app
mix ecto.create
mix ecto.migrate
git init && git add . && git commit -m "Initial commit"
heroku create
```

This gives me a Heroku instance:

```
Creating app... done, ⬢ first-instance-12345
https://first-instance-12345.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/first-instance-12345.git
```

I then add the buildpacks, change the `config/` files and run `git push heroku master` and everything works.

Now I'd like to create another Heroku instance, to which I can also deploy.  If I run `heroku create` again, I get:

```
Creating app... done, ⬢ second-instance-23456
https://second-instance-23456.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/second-instance-23456.git
```

If I replace the url in prod.exs with the new instance...

```
config :my_app,  MyApp.Endpoint,
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [scheme: "https", host: "second-instance-23456.herokuapp.com", port: 443], force_ssl: [rewrite_on: [:x_forwarded_proto]],
```

...and then commit and run `git push heroku master`, it will still deploy to first-instance-12345.herokuapp.com, which isn't what I want.

Re-running buildpacks doesn't help either.

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir
 ▸    The buildpack https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir is already set on your app.
$ heroku buildpacks:add https://github.com/gjaldon/phoenix-static-buildpack
 ▸    The buildpack https://github.com/gjaldon/phoenix-static-buildpack is already set on your app.
```

Is there a standard method (or any method) to get Phoenix to deploy to multiple heroku environments?  (And hopefully specify which one/s on deploy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to deploy an app to multiple Heroku apps is to add multiple remotes to the repo and push to the one you want to deploy to. Making that change to `config/prod.exs` will have no effect on where the app is deployed.

Here's how to add the two remotes:

```
$ git remote add first https://git.heroku.com/first-instance-12345.git
$ git remote add second https://git.heroku.com/second-instance-23456.git
```

Now you can deploy to the first one using:

```
$ git push first master
```

and to the second using:

```
$ git push second master
```

Comment: Getting this:
`remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        npm ERR! addLocal Could not install /tmp/build_281dbc927c24aa3bb5ad67f310924ca2/deps/phoenix
remote:        npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
remote:        npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.`
...are there any intermediate steps?

Comment: `remote:        - Node version not specified in package.json`....I added `  "engines": { "npm": "7.6.0" }`, but to no avail.

Comment: Does this happen only on the new (second) remote? Try adding all the buildpacks to the second app: `heroku buildpacks:add --app second-instance-23456 https://github.com/...` (just like you did for the first one without the `--app` argument) and then push again.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't specify the app at creation.  See edit above, and feel free to edit to your liking.

Comment: Actually you don't need to do that if you've already created the apps. You can use the command in my previous comment to add the buildpack to any existing app.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. `heroku create --remote third` `git remote add third https://git.heroku.com/third-app-34567.git`...results in...`fatal: remote third already exists.`

Comment: I meant add a buildpack like in my third comment. If you create an app with `--remote`, the git remote is added already, you don't need to do that.

Comment: `$ heroku create --remote third`...`$ heroku buildpacks:add --app third-app-34567 https://github.com/third-app-34567.git`...`$ git push third master`....results in: `remote:  !     error fetching custom buildpack`.

Comment: `heroku buildpacks:add --app third-app-34567 https://github.com/HashNuke/heroku-buildpack-elixir`, `heroku buildpacks:add --app third-app-34567 https://github.com/gjaldon/phoenix-static-buildpack`

Comment: ah, that looks like what I have in the Edit, with a different placement of the `--app` clause.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly the best way to do so is to have two different instances as @dogbert wrote.
Also remember about changing Procfile for heroku, because you want to run app using different environments eg.

```
# Procfile for prod
web: MIX_ENV=prod mix phoenix.server

# Procfile for dev
web: MIX_ENV=dev mix phoenix.server
```

For both environments you would need to apply migrations:

```
heroku run MIX_ENV=<env> ecto.migrate
```

Comment: Let's assume I have two heroku apps, foo and bar, each with their own `app-name-12345.herokuapp.com` address and I push with `git push foo|bar master`.  Heroku only knows of them as foo and bar; it has no concept of whether one is dev/staging or production.  Does that get indicated in the Procfile?

Comment: Yes, Procfile is used to tell heroku which command should call. In this case you control what env you fire with MIX_ENV variable.